# How to properly optimize a query in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There is a query of the following type that takes a long time (in a collection of millions of records), the indexes are set on the _id and cpe_id fields, the state. How to understand the matter in the $ in operator due to the increase in search and also because of the large collection, as I have complexity O (N * logM), where N is the length in in, M is the number of elements in the collection. Are there any options to somehow improve the performance of the query?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match :
        {"cpe_id" :
            {$in : ["e389439e-bd04-f3fb-c512-00193b0c4385","d389439e-bd04-f3fb-c512-00193b13d00c"....]}
        }
    },
        {$sort : {state: 1, _id : 1}},
        {$skip : 0},
        {$limit : 100},
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$in` operator can be effectively serviced by an index on the queried field, i.e. `{cpe_id: 1}`.

In terms of performance, it will need to scan one region of the index for each value in the provided array.  I would expect that part to scale linearly with the array size.

The sort can be accomplished using an index as well, but MongoDB can use only one index to perform the sort, and it must be the same index used to select the documents.

If there is no single index that can be use for both, it will first find all matching documents, load them into memory, sort them, and only then apply the skip and limit.

If there is an index on `{cpe_id: 1, state: 1, _id: 1}` or `{state: 1, _id: 1, cpe_id: 1}`  there are several optimizations the query planner can use:

- documents are selected using the index, so no non-matching documents are loaded
- since the values in the index are already sorted in the desired order, it can omit the in-memory sort
- without the blocking sort, the execution can halt after (skip + limit) documents have been found.

You can use the [db.collection.explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html#db-collection-explain) shell helper or [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html#db-collection-explain) command with the "allPlansExecution" option to see which indexes were considered, and how each performed.